# Angular multiple router outlets

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an angular 6 application that I am trying to use multiple router-outlets with but cannot get the navigation to work.

My app.component looks like this

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I then have a home component which has a navigation bar on the left hand side and a main section to the right of it. I am using this to display content in the main section without affecting the navigation bar on the left

```
<div toolbar></div>
<div mainSection>
   <router-outlet name="mainoutlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

My routing module looks like as follows

```
 path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard], children:
  [{ path: '', component: MainSectionComponent, outlet: 'mainoutlet' },
    { path: 'test1', component: Test1Component, pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'test2', component: Test2Component, pathMatch: 'full' }
```

The MainSectionComponent is loaded correctly within the main section, however whenever I try to navigate to test1 or test2 it fails with an Angular error in the console.

I am trying to navigate using a the following code in a service.

```
    this.router.navigate('test1');
```

I am wondering if its because its being called from a service that its failing but I dont know. I have tried using a non-named router-outlet but this gives me the same result. I have also tried moving the routes out of the maincomponent children but this also does not work.

For reference, my setup looks to be exactly the same as https://stackblitz.com/angular/aepvpqmoqaj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. The only difference being I am using a service to navigate rather than routerLinks in the html. That said I have noticed this code also fails with the same Angular error that I am receiving.

Comment: Remove all the pathMatch attributes, remove `name="mainoutlet"`, remove `outlet: 'mainoutlet'`. Use `this.router.navigate('/test1');`

Comment: This hasnt worked unfortunately, I still get the same ERROR Error: "[object Object]".

Comment: This is much too vague. Post a complete minimal reproduction as a stackblitz.

Comment: If you look at the stackblitz I referenced, I cant see any difference between that and what I am trying except for the use of a service for navigation. Regardless you get the same error in that stackblitz that I am getting, presumably it would be the same fix for both

Comment: I don't get any error with the stackblitz you shared. Post **your own** stackblitz, which reproduces the error. I can't find an error in code if I don't know what the error is and what the code is.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vu6ee1 There is my version, when you click the test button that should change the component below but instead I just get an error in the console

Comment: You didn't remove the pathMatch attribute. Do it, and it will work fine.

Comment: Thankyou so much, I feel like an idiot now! I removed it from all the child components but not the root one.